# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function on Google Plus Login

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-plus

I'm trying to implement Google plus login and its my code

```
$('#GPlogin').on('click', function () {

  var myParams = {
    'clientid' : 'My ID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    'cookiepolicy' : 'single_host_origin',
    'callback' : 'GPlogin',
    'approvalprompt':'force',
    'scope' : 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read'
  };
  gapi.auth.signIn(myParams);

}); 


function GPlogin(result)
{
    console.log(result);
    if(result['status']['signed_in'])
    {
        var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get(
        {
            'userId': 'me'
        });
        request.execute(function (resp)
        {
            var email = '';
            if(resp['emails'])
            {
                for(i = 0; i < resp['emails'].length; i++)
                {
                    if(resp['emails'][i]['type'] == 'account')
                    {
                        email = resp['emails'][i]['value'];
                    }
                }
            }

            var str = "Name:" + resp['displayName'] + "<br>";
            str += "Image:" + resp['image']['url'] + "<br>";
            str += "<img src='" + resp['image']['url'] + "' /><br>";

            str += "URL:" + resp['url'] + "<br>";
            str += "Email:" + email + "<br>";
            console.log(str);
        });

    }

}


function onLoadCallback()
{
    //gapi.client.setApiKey('My API Key'); //set your API KEY
    gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1',function(){});//Load Google + API
}



(function() {
  var po = document.createElement('script');
  po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
  po.src = 'https://plus.google.com/js/client:plusone.js?onload=loadGApi';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})();
```

For first time modal window asked my for permissions and then in console i got error

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

after when I'm pressing on login button modal asks my for offline use permission and am getting the same error in console

Comment: On what line is the error thrown?

Comment: Just a tip: `undefined is not a function` happens when you call a function (by putting the `()`) after something in something that evaluates to `undefined`. Generally it happens like: `myObject.somePropertyThatIThinkThatExistsButDoesnt()`

Comment: @James error is on cb=gapi.loaded_0:353

Comment: @Rafael there is just one function with `()` `gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1',function(){});`

Comment: Then `load` is probably an `undefined`, whatever that means in your code.